# FRP Locked and Doesn't UNLOCK WITH CORRECT CREDENTIALS

Tags: tablet, lenovo, frp

I've got a *Lenovo Tab 3 Essential*. Due to a forgetting my password, I've reset that by Android Recovery boot.
Now it asks about my google account. **I enter the correct email address and password but nothing!**. It says

> Due to a UNKNOWN PROBLEM, CANNOT COMPLETE THE ACTION. TRY AGAIN IN 24 HOURS

Please help me.

Comment: maybe it is helpful to connect wifi and wait 24 h. But by-pass FRP is possible with SP Flash Tool. first step is [creating your own scatter file](https://forum.hovatek.com/thread-21970.html) (i strongly recommend not to use any downloaded scatter), second step format the FRP partition with values from the scatter file, for **EXAMPLE**
`region: EMMC_USER` -
`linear_start_addr: 0x5d00000` -
`partition_size: 0x100000`

Comment: Thank you. I've connected wifi and I have been wait for 24 hours. NOTHING HAPPENS